# Change background color of a column in a sharepoint list

Tags: json, list, sharepoint

I've been trying to change the background color of a column in a Sharepoint list without full success.

I've been using below JSON code but what bugs me is that it don't fill out the whole cell.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "debugMode": true,
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "pink"
  }
}
```

[Current sharepoint list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6geCQ.png)

Do you have any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the `min-height` property set.

As a workaround, you could enlarge the `min-height` to make it fill out the whole cell.

Example:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "debugMode": true,
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
     "min-height":"56px",
    "background-color": "pink"
  }
}
```