# Json Background color fill column of div - parent height

Tags: html, css, json, sharepoint

I see alot of answers for css and html combined but i am looking for help with JSON formatting a sharepoint list.

The list looks like image below after i enter the json but i need the background color to extend the entire height of the DIV...

Hoping someone can help, i cant figure this one out.. Here is the JSON:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideListHeader": true,
  "hideSelection": true,
  "rowFormatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
      "position": "relative",
      "width": "100%",
      "border-style": "solid",
      "border-width": "thin",
      "border-color": "#102c3c",
      "box-sizing": "border-box",
      "height": "100%",
      "margin": "5px 0",
      "box-shadow": "0 4px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06)"
      
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "button",
        "customRowAction": {
          "action": "defaultClick"
        },
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-bgColor-white ms-bgColor-themeLighter--hover"
        },
        "style": {
          "width": "100%",
          "display": "flex",
          "padding": 0,
          "height": "100%",
          "border": "none",
          "cursor": "pointer"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {},
            "style": {
              "min-width": "150px","background-color": "red",
              "display": "flex",
              "height": "100%",
              "box-sizing": "border-box",
              "align-items": "stretch"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "iconName": "=if([$Category] == 'Action Needed', 'warning', if([$Category] == 'Documentation', 'Document', if([$Category] == 'Information', 'Info', 'Tag')))",
                  "class": "ms-fontSize-m ms-fontWeight-regular  ms-fontColor-grey",
                  "title": "[$Category]"
                },
                "style": {
                  "flex": "none",
                  "padding": "10px",
                  "padding-left": "18px",
                  "padding-top": "16px",
                  "align-items": "stretch"
                }
              },
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "style": {
                  "flex-grow": "1",
                  "text-align": "left",
                  
                  "align-items": "center"
                },
                "children": [
                  {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "ms-fontSize-m ms-fontWeight-semibold ms-fontColor-gray",
                      "title": "=toLocaleDateString([$Modified])"
                    },
                    "style": {
                      "margin-right": "12px",
                      "overflow": "hidden",
                      "white-space": "nowrap",
                      "align-items": "center"
                    },
                    "txtContent": "=toLocaleDateString([$Modified])"
                  },
                  {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "ms-fontSize-m ms-fontWeight-lighter ms-fontColor-gray",
                      "title": "[$Category]"
                    },
                    "style": {
                      "margin-right": "12px",
                      "overflow": "hidden",
                      "white-space": "nowrap",
                      "height": "100%",
                      "font-size": "12px",
                      "align-items": "center"
                    },
                    "txtContent": "[$Category]"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-borderColor-themePrimary ms-fontWeight-semibold ms-fontSize-l"
            },
            "style": {
              "border-left": ".1mm double",
              "border-left-style": "ridge",
              "border-left-color": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary",
              "width": "100%",
              "min-height": "42px",
              "height": "100%",
              "text-align": "left",
              "padding": "1px 40px 2px 8px",
              "overflow": "hidden"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "txtContent": "=substring(@currentField, 0, 75) + '...'",
                "style": {
                  "overflow": "clip",
                  "text-decoration": "none"
                },
                "attributes": {
                  "title": "[$Title]",
                  "class": "ms-fontWeight-semibold ms-fontSize-m"
                }
              },
              {
                "elmType": "a",
                "txtContent": "=if ([$Category] == 'Action Needed', [$TakeActionText], '')",
                "style": {
                  "overflow": "clip",
                  "text-decoration": "none"
                },
                "attributes": {
                  "target": "_blank",
                  "class": "ms-fontSize-s ms-fontWeight-semibold ms-fontColor-lightblue",
                  "href": "[$URL]"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "elmType": "button",
        "customRowAction": {
          "action": "share"
        },
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-fontColor-themeLight ms-fontColor-themeDark--hover",
          "title": "Share Item"
        },
        "style": {
          "border": "none",
          "background-color": "transparent",
          "cursor": "pointer",
          "position": "absolute",
          "top": "12px",
          "right": "0"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "span",
            "attributes": {
              "iconName": "Share",
              "class": "ms-font-l"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NXCW.png)

Comment: I am currently doing some research on this issue, will let you know as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

According to my research and testing, this is due to the `min-height` property set.

Please try to enlarge the `min-height` to make it fill out the whole cell.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
      "min-height": "50px"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgPeach sp-css-borderColor-PeachFont sp-field-fontSizeSmall sp-css-color-PeachFont"
  }
}
```

My test result:

[image]

Similar issue for reference :[Change background color of a column in a sharepoint list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59706211/change-background-color-of-a-column-in-a-sharepoint-list)

Comment: Do you have any further questions about this thread? If you have any questions or progress, you can contact me in time.